# C# for loop in html MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hello I have the following for loop within html. I want to know how to output value i - 1. With the code below the output of the value ends up being:

```
0-1
1-1
2-1
3-1
4-1

@for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    <input type="text" name="name_@i-1" value="@i-1">
}
```

The correct value of inputs should be the following:

```
-1
0
1
2
3
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Should you not put parentheses for the computation?

```
@for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    <input type="text" name="name_@(i-1)" value="@(i-1)">
}
```

When you do not put the parentheses, only `i` is considered C# code while `-1` is simply rendered as text. For that reason you got your result, only the first number comes from `i`:

```
i-1 //
---
0-1
1-1
2-1
3-1
4-1
```

Answer (score 1):

The value after the `-` is not being interpreted as part of the Razor expression. Use parentheses:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    <input type="text" name="name_@(i-1)" value="@(i-1)">
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure why it was hard to find this information!